# Nokia N97 Related to sensor Api and some java logic

Tags: java, java-me

Myself shweta dodiya.I am having an problem related to sensor and logic in j2me which i had implemented for achieving the result in my project.The logic which i had implemented is as follows:-

```
sensor= (SensorConnection) Connector.open("sensor:acceleration");
 try {
                data = sensor.getData(1);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
                value[i] = data[i].getDoubleValues()[0];
            }
            CurrentValX = value[0];//X-axis of sensor
            CurrentValY = value[1];//y-axis of sensor

            if (CurrentValX < PreValueX1) {
                left = false;
                right = true;

            } else if (CurrentValX > PreValueX1) {
                left = true;
                right = false;

            }
            if (CurrentValY < PreValueY1) {
                down = false;
                up = true;

            } else if (CurrentValY > PreValueY1) {
                down = true;
                up = false;

            }
        if (right == true && ballX < Scrwidth - 15) {
            ballX += 4;
        } else if (left == true && ballX > 15) {
            ballX -= 4;
        }
        if (down == true && ballY < Scrheight - 15) {
            ballY += 4;
        } else if (up == true && ballY > 15) {
            ballY -= 4;
        }
            CurrentValY = PreValueY1;
            CurrentValX = PreValueX1;
        //check for the collision of ball with the other object like brick


if (bricksprite.collidesWith(ballSprite, true)) { 

            if (right) {
                ballX -= 10;
            }
            if (left) {
                ballX += 10;
            }
            if (up) {
                ballY += 10;
            }
            if (down) {
                ballX -= 10;
            }                
        }
```

The problem i am having is in the collision of the ball and the bricks.when it get collide i want to move ball in the opposite direction of the collision.But sometime the ball instead of moving in opposite direction it keep moving in same direction.I had getting the direction of the ball through the boolean up,down,left,right.

Please help me to solve it and guide me and correct me if i m wrong somewhere

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Read about VECTORS in Math, and implement them in your code. You will then get much simpler code and much natural looking game! To reverse the balls trajectory, reverse its vector. To set it moving 90deg forward, rotate its vector by 90deg... You should never make linear changes to the objects coordinates like you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't read your code , But in past I have coded the same kinda game,

In that I have applied following logic;

1.when ball colides suppose consider ball is moving from right to left than collides at left wall at some angel.  here your x and y was decreasing in uniform manner upon colission your x should increase while y should be decreasing with the same fashion.

2.when ball colides vertical wall , y should invert x should be same..

I hope it clears up the logic.